# Force Entity Framework Core to reload some fields after SaveChanges is called

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a project using Entity Framework Core to insert/update records in a table in Postgres and I have cases where the numeric precision of some values in C# is higher than the numeric precision of Postgres.

For example, I might have the number the number `0.99878` in memory on a property of type `double` in C#, but when I save this value it might be stored in Posgres as `0.9988` instead, and that's totally fine and expected.

Entity Framework doesn't know about what Postgres did when storing this number, and everything seems fine, but in reality the number I have in-memory is incorrect unless I manually tell EF to refresh the entity.

**I can't increase the precision in the database**, but I would like to avoid having to manually refresh entities after every `SaveChanges`

How can I tell Entity Framework Core to automatically refresh some fields after `SaveChanges`?

I tried setting `.ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` but that ignores the value that I have in memory.

Comment: IMHO, use a decimal type, verify / round to the same precision before you save.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyLakeman that's a workaround but I have more than one field with the same characteristic so it's more work to check each field, than to ask EF to reload the whole entity again - I'm just hoping there's a way to avoid even that, and have EF reload the field automatically

Comment: @TheGeneral This is not very different from having auto generated fields (from the database) or having a database trigger that overrides a value depending on some condition. The question is how can we tell EF that the field that it saved may have changed after the insert or update, so that it can reload it automatically - just like it does for identity fields.

Comment: Actually you are right, i rescind my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in the Entity Framework opensource repository and this feature does not exist (at least today with the current .NET 5 release) and was added to the backlog for consideration.

> **Support store-generated values that are both written to and also read back from the database in the same command**
>
> https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23196#issuecomment-723494947

Answer (score 1):

Silently losing precision is certainly a problem. For my own use case, involving tracking currency, I found that behaviour to be unacceptable. To keep code repetition to a minimum  I introduced a validation attribute, forced every decimal in the model to have it, used it to define the column type in the database, and re-validate every modified object before saving.

```cs
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class PrecisionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public PrecisionAttribute(int precision, int scale)
        {
            Precision = precision;
            Scale = scale;
        }

        public int Precision { get; set; }
        public int Scale { get; set; }
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value is decimal val)
            {
                if (val == 0)
                    return true;
                var sqlDec = new SqlDecimal(val);
                try
                {
                    return (sqlDec == SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(sqlDec, Precision, Scale)).Value;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            var dec = value as decimal?;
            return !dec.HasValue || IsValid(dec.Value);
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (IsValid(value))
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            return new ValidationResult($"'{value}' is not a valid {validationContext.DisplayName}", new string[] { validationContext.MemberName });
        }
        
        public void Apply(IMutableProperty property) => property.SetColumnType($"numeric({Precision},{Scale})");
    }

    // ... DbContext ...
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        //...
            foreach (var table in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var col in table.GetProperties())
                {
                    var precision = col.PropertyInfo?.GetCustomAttribute<PrecisionAttribute>() ?? col.FieldInfo?.GetCustomAttribute<PrecisionAttribute>();
                    if (precision != null)
                        precision.Apply(col);
                    else if(col.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || col.ClrType == typeof(decimal?))
                        throw new Exception($"Decimal column {table.ClrType.Name}.{col.Name} doesn't have a precision!");
                }
            }
        }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            PreSave();
            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override int SaveChanges(bool accept) {
            PreSave();
            return base.SaveChanges(accept);
        }

        private void PreSave()
        {
            if (!ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
                return;

            var serviceProvider = this.GetService<IServiceProvider>();
            var items = new Dictionary<object, object>();
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        var context = new ValidationContext(entry.Entity, serviceProvider, items);
                        Validator.ValidateObject(entry.Entity, context, true);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy Lakeman. That's an interesting approach for sure. In my case precision is not important and I have too many fields to worry about and they have different precisions... I only care about display what's stored in the database in the UI, so all I want is an automatic refresh of some fields so I don't return incorrect data to the UI after saving.  ps: I upvoted your answer but it seems I don't have enough reputation yet for it to count :(.

Comment: Now that custom value conversions are a thing, you could also hide the decimal / double value inside a struct so you can round the value to match the db rounding when the value is set.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, it's just that in my scenario, I don't own the database and I don't want to have to know what precision they use in every field (and then have to round correctly in my app) and forever having to keep it synchronized with the database whenever the owners of the DB change the precision of the fields - That's a big burden